# Having an Excel VBA Error - as if VBA cannot see objects and cannot select cells

Tags: excel, vba, ide

I have a VBA error on a work laptop (Windows 10/Office 2016). Office has been reinstalled and I still have the error. The usual VBA references are present, including Object library 16.0. The issue affects the recording of code, e.g. recording adding values into cells looks like this (rather than the usual R1C1 style):

Full code below:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
'
    Range("A1").Select
    . = "1"
    Range("A2").Select
    . = "2"
    Range("A3").Select
    . = "3"
    Range("A4").Select
End Sub
```

If I use the select only section I get the following error code: Method 'Select' of Object '_Worksheet failed '-2147319784 (80028018)'. This seems to relate to language or region not being English, however both the system setting and Office setting are set to English UK.

Comment: `. = "1"` looks like a syntax error. If your macro recorder is producing code that has syntax errors, something is deeply wrong with your installation, something which seems unrelated to regional settings.

Comment: Could you show the complete, recorded code, not just an extract, please. Use the [edit] link under the question to do so. Also, is this happening in only one workbook, or is it with any workbook? Have you tried REPAIRING Office (not simply re-installing)? Does the problem also happen with Word, or only Excel?

Comment: Repair has been carried out and has not rectified the VBA issue. I have added the full code in the original question. Issue happens in all workbooks. Just to add, VBA does not work with auto filters. If recording, the code is not written to add one and when using pre-written code it generates an error.

Comment: A DLL that VBA is using is possibly corrupt. A reinstall might just check if it exists on your system rather than reinstalling it.